# Elasticsearch bool query with filter and should

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

My main aim is to write a query that must search for the searchtext and if any filter of loading port or unloading port is applied then it must filter that from the result of search text.

And if no filter is applied then it should proceed further.

For eg:  I search for jeans and if I apply filter then the loading port must be India and its unloading port must be US.

I tried to write this report but it's not giving appropriate result.

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": searchText
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "loadingPort":loadingPortArray
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "unloadingPort":unloadingPortArray
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are wrapping all the quires\filters inside `should`, which means that all the statements with be combined by `OR` logic. If you need `AND` you need to wrap statements inside `must`.

By the way, you are not using filter, you are using `term` query. There is huge difference between query and filter in elasticsearch. To use filter you need to use `bool` query with filter.

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": searchText
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }        
      ],
      "filter": {
          "bool": {
              "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                        "loadingPort":loadingPortArray
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                        "unloadingPort":loadingPortArray
                    }
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanku for the response. But My main problem is when the user does not apply any filter i.e. loading port array and unloading port array is empty. In that case this is throwing an error.

Comment: you cannot apply conditional filters. instead of that you need to build your query conditionally and filters if they are exists

Comment: Can you please guide me what condition I should use when there is no filter applied.

Comment: just do not add filter property to the query